# Show that if $f(x)>0$ for $x\in Q$, then $\int_Q f>0.$ Is there any very easy proof? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
The following exercise (Exercise 9 on p.98) is in this book:

> 9. Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:Q\to\mathbb{R}$; assume $f$ is integrable over $Q$.
>    (a) Show that if $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in Q$, then $\int_Q f\geq 0$.
>    (b) Show that if $f(x)>0$ for $x\in Q$, then $\int_Q f>0$.

(a) is very easy and we can easily solve (a) from the definition of the integral over $Q$.
At first glance, I thought (b) is similar to (a) and I can easily solve (b) from the definition of the integral over $Q$.
But I couldn't solve (b) directly from the definition of the integral over $Q$.
Finally I had to use the following theorem to solve (b).

> Theorem 11.3. Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:Q\to\mathbb{R}$; assume $f$ is integrable over $Q$.
> (b) If $f$ is non-negative and if $\int_Q f=0$, then $f$ vanishes except on a set of measure zero.

My solution of Exercise 9(b):

> By Exercise 9(a), $\int_Q f\geq 0$.
> Assume that $\int_Q f=0$.
> $f$ is positive, so $f$ is non-negative.
> And $\int_Q f=0$ by our assumption.
> So, by Theorem 11.3(b), $f$ vanishes except on $D$ which is a set of measure zero.
> So, $\{x\in Q\mid f(x)\neq 0\}\subset D.$
> Since $D$ is a set of measure zero, $\{x\in Q\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ is also a set of measure zero.
> But $\{x\in Q\mid f(x)\neq 0\}=Q$ and $Q$ is not a set of measure zero by Theorem 11.1(d) on p.91.
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $\int_Q f>0$.

Is there any very easy proof of Exercise 9(b)?

Comment: This is fine and as  simple as it can be.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: If you know that $f$ is continuous except perhaps on a set of measure zero, then you can find an $x\in \text{int} Q$ at which $f$ is continuous. Then, $f>\epsilon$ on some closed rectangle $Q'\subseteq Q$ for some $\epsilon>0.$ And so $\int_Qf\ge\int_{Q'}f>\epsilon\text{vol}Q'>0$

Comment: @Matematleta Thank you very much for your comment.